# jQuery override containment option, only allow space not used by sibling elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to have a custom widget that allows an element to be resizable with height and width limited by its parent element. The containment options on the resizable widget allows this but I need one extra criteria. I need to only allow the element to be sized in the space not used by sibling elements... If you use the resizable widget on element .xyz it will limit .xyz to the parent elements boundaries but will push element .xyz's siblings outside the parent elements boundaries! How can I implement this extra criteria?

If you don't understand what I'm trying to do I might be able to explain it better, please let me know.

I got this working once before but I wasn't happy with how I achieved it. I posted on another forum but never got any help.

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?274379-jQuery-UI-Resizable-Widget&p=1254637#post1254637

EDIT:

I was able to do this in a way that is much better than what I posted to webdevelper.com.
I attached a custom $.ui.plugin.add method to the "resizable" widget. Now I can pass the resizable widget an option of "siblings: parent", this allows the criteria I stated above. If you know of a better way to do this please let me know. I this think there must be a more direct way that involves less code copying. I copied the entire containment method and used it as my siblings method.

```
function num(v) {
     return parseInt(v, 10) || 0;
}


$.ui.plugin.add("resizable", "siblings", {

    start: function() {

        var element, p, co, ch, cw, width, height,
        that = $(this).data("ui-resizable"),
        o = that.options,
        el = that.element,
        oc = o.siblings,
        ce = (oc instanceof $) ? oc.get(0) : (/parent/.test(oc)) ? el.parent().get(0)
 : oc;

    if (!ce) {
        return;
    }

    that.containerElement = $(ce);

    if (/document/.test(oc) || oc === document) {
        that.containerOffset = {
            left: 0, 
            top: 0
        };
        that.containerPosition = {
            left: 0, 
            top: 0
        };

        that.parentData = {
            element: $(document), 
            left: 0, 
            top: 0,
            width: $(document).width(), 
            height: $(document).height() || document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight
        };
    }

    // i'm a node, so compute top, left, right, bottom
    else {
        element = $(ce);
        p = [];
        //set the padding of the container element
        $([ "Top", "Right", "Left", "Bottom" ]).each(function(i, name) {
            p[i] = num(element.css("padding" + name));   
        });

        //collection of sibling elements
        var siblings = el.siblings();
        var sHeight = 0;

        siblings.each(function(){
            console.log($(this).height());
            var element = $("#" + this.id);
            var marginHeight = parseInt(element.css("margin-top")) +  
 parseInt(element.css("margin-bottom"));
            var borderHeight = parseInt(element.css("border-top-width")) + 
  parseInt(element.css("border-bottom-width")); 
            sHeight = sHeight + ($(this).height() + marginHeight + borderHeight);
        });

        that.containerOffset = element.offset();
        that.containerPosition = element.position();
        that.containerSize = {
            height: ((element.innerHeight() - p[3]) - sHeight), 
            width: (element.innerWidth() - p[1])
        };

        co = that.containerOffset;
        ch = that.containerSize.height;
        cw = that.containerSize.width;
        width = ($.ui.hasScroll(ce, "left") ? ce.scrollWidth : cw );
        height = ($.ui.hasScroll(ce) ? ce.scrollHeight : ch);

        that.parentData = {
            element: ce, 
            left: co.left, 
            top: co.top, 
            width: width, 
            height: height
        };
    }
},

resize: function( event ) {

    console.log("resizing");

    var woset, hoset, isParent, isOffsetRelative,
    that = $(this).data("ui-resizable"),
    o = that.options,
    co = that.containerOffset, cp = that.position,
    pRatio = that._aspectRatio || event.shiftKey,
    cop = {
        top:0, 
        left:0
    }, ce = that.containerElement;

    if (ce[0] !== document && (/static/).test(ce.css("position"))) {
        cop = co;
    }

    if (cp.left < (that._helper ? co.left : 0)) {
        that.size.width = that.size.width + (that._helper ? (that.position.left - 
co.left) : (that.position.left - cop.left));
        if (pRatio) {
            that.size.height = that.size.width / that.aspectRatio;
        }
        that.position.left = o.helper ? co.left : 0;
    }

    if (cp.top < (that._helper ? co.top : 0)) {
        that.size.height = that.size.height + (that._helper ? (that.position.top - 
co.top) : that.position.top);
        if (pRatio) {
            that.size.width = that.size.height * that.aspectRatio;
        }
        that.position.top = that._helper ? co.top : 0;
    }

    that.offset.left = that.parentData.left+that.position.left;
    that.offset.top = that.parentData.top+that.position.top;

    woset = Math.abs( (that._helper ? that.offset.left - cop.left : (that.offset.left
     - cop.left)) + that.sizeDiff.width );
    hoset = Math.abs( (that._helper ? that.offset.top - cop.top : (that.offset.top - 
    co.top)) + that.sizeDiff.height );

    isParent = that.containerElement.get(0) === that.element.parent().get(0);
    isOffsetRelative = /relative|absolute/.test(that.containerElement.css("position"));

    if(isParent && isOffsetRelative) {
        woset -= that.parentData.left;
    }

    if (woset + that.size.width >= that.parentData.width) {
        that.size.width = that.parentData.width - woset;
        if (pRatio) {
            that.size.height = that.size.width / that.aspectRatio;
        }
    }

    if (hoset + that.size.height >= that.parentData.height) {
        that.size.height = that.parentData.height - hoset;
        if (pRatio) {
            that.size.width = that.size.height * that.aspectRatio;
        }
    }
},

stop: function(){
    var that = $(this).data("ui-resizable"),
    o = that.options,
    co = that.containerOffset,
    cop = that.containerPosition,
    ce = that.containerElement,
    helper = $(that.helper),
    ho = helper.offset(),
    w = helper.outerWidth() - that.sizeDiff.width,
    h = helper.outerHeight() - that.sizeDiff.height;

    if (that._helper && !o.animate && (/relative/).test(ce.css("position"))) {
        $(this).css({
            left: ho.left - cop.left - co.left, 
            width: w, 
            height: h
        });
    }

        if (that._helper && !o.animate && (/static/).test(ce.css("position"))) {
            $(this).css({
                left: ho.left - cop.left - co.left, 
                width: w, 
                height: h
            });
        }

    }
});


$(function(){

        $( "#resizable1").resizable({
            siblings: "parent"
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, I wrapped the sibling functionality in a new widget called staticblock. I plan to extend the staticblock widget further, but the way it is now it will be aware of sibling elements thereby not pushing siblings outside the parent when elements are re-sized.

```
    function num(v) {
        return parseInt(v, 10) || 0;
    }


    $.widget("pf.staticblock", {

        _create: function() {
            var ele = this.element;

            this._makeResizable(ele);
        },

        _makeResizable: function(ele) {
            ele.resizable({
                siblings: "parent"
            });
        }

    });

    $.ui.plugin.add("resizable", "siblings", {

        start: function() {
            console.log("started");

            var element, p, co, ch, cw, width, height,
            that = $(this).data("ui-resizable"),
            o = that.options,
            el = that.element,
            oc = o.siblings,
            ce = (oc instanceof $) ? oc.get(0) : (/parent/.test(oc)) ? el.parent().get(0) : oc;

            if (!ce) {
                return;
            }

            that.containerElement = $(ce);

            if (/document/.test(oc) || oc === document) {
                that.containerOffset = {
                    left: 0, 
                    top: 0
                };
                that.containerPosition = {
                    left: 0, 
                    top: 0
                };

                that.parentData = {
                    element: $(document), 
                    left: 0, 
                    top: 0,
                    width: $(document).width(), 
                    height: $(document).height() || document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight
                };
            }

            // i'm a node, so compute top, left, right, bottom
            else {
                element = $(ce);
                p = [];
                //set the padding of the container element
                $([ "Top", "Right", "Left", "Bottom" ]).each(function(i, name) {
                    p[i] = num(element.css("padding" + name));   
                });

                //collection of sibling elements
                var siblings = el.siblings();
                var sHeight = 0;
                console.log(this.id);
                siblings.each(function(){
                    console.log($(this).height());
                    var element = $("#" + this.id);
                    var marginHeight = parseInt(element.css("margin-top")) + parseInt(element.css("margin-bottom"));
                    var borderHeight = parseInt(element.css("border-top-width")) + parseInt(element.css("border-bottom-width")); 
                    sHeight = sHeight + ($(this).height() + marginHeight + borderHeight);
                });

                that.containerOffset = element.offset();
                that.containerPosition = element.position();
                that.containerSize = {
                    height: ((element.innerHeight() - p[3]) - sHeight), 
                    width: (element.innerWidth() - p[1])
                };

                co = that.containerOffset;
                ch = that.containerSize.height;
                cw = that.containerSize.width;
                width = ($.ui.hasScroll(ce, "left") ? ce.scrollWidth : cw );
                height = ($.ui.hasScroll(ce) ? ce.scrollHeight : ch);

                that.parentData = {
                    element: ce, 
                    left: co.left, 
                    top: co.top, 
                    width: width, 
                    height: height
                };
            }
        },

        resize: function( event ) {

            console.log("resizing");

            var woset, hoset, isParent, isOffsetRelative,
            that = $(this).data("ui-resizable"),
            o = that.options,
            co = that.containerOffset, cp = that.position,
            pRatio = that._aspectRatio || event.shiftKey,
            cop = {
                top:0, 
                left:0
            }, ce = that.containerElement;

            if (ce[0] !== document && (/static/).test(ce.css("position"))) {
                cop = co;
            }

            if (cp.left < (that._helper ? co.left : 0)) {
                that.size.width = that.size.width + (that._helper ? (that.position.left - co.left) : (that.position.left - cop.left));
                if (pRatio) {
                    that.size.height = that.size.width / that.aspectRatio;
                }
                that.position.left = o.helper ? co.left : 0;
            }

            if (cp.top < (that._helper ? co.top : 0)) {
                that.size.height = that.size.height + (that._helper ? (that.position.top - co.top) : that.position.top);
                if (pRatio) {
                    that.size.width = that.size.height * that.aspectRatio;
                }
                that.position.top = that._helper ? co.top : 0;
            }

            that.offset.left = that.parentData.left+that.position.left;
            that.offset.top = that.parentData.top+that.position.top;

            woset = Math.abs( (that._helper ? that.offset.left - cop.left : (that.offset.left - cop.left)) + that.sizeDiff.width );
            hoset = Math.abs( (that._helper ? that.offset.top - cop.top : (that.offset.top - co.top)) + that.sizeDiff.height );

            isParent = that.containerElement.get(0) === that.element.parent().get(0);
            isOffsetRelative = /relative|absolute/.test(that.containerElement.css("position"));

            if(isParent && isOffsetRelative) {
                woset -= that.parentData.left;
            }

            if (woset + that.size.width >= that.parentData.width) {
                that.size.width = that.parentData.width - woset;
                if (pRatio) {
                    that.size.height = that.size.width / that.aspectRatio;
                }
            }

            if (hoset + that.size.height >= that.parentData.height) {
                that.size.height = that.parentData.height - hoset;
                if (pRatio) {
                    that.size.width = that.size.height * that.aspectRatio;
                }
            }
        },

        stop: function(){
            var that = $(this).data("ui-resizable"),
            o = that.options,
            co = that.containerOffset,
            cop = that.containerPosition,
            ce = that.containerElement,
            helper = $(that.helper),
            ho = helper.offset(),
            w = helper.outerWidth() - that.sizeDiff.width,
            h = helper.outerHeight() - that.sizeDiff.height;

            if (that._helper && !o.animate && (/relative/).test(ce.css("position"))) {
                $(this).css({
                    left: ho.left - cop.left - co.left, 
                    width: w, 
                    height: h
                });
            }

            if (that._helper && !o.animate && (/static/).test(ce.css("position"))) {
                $(this).css({
                    left: ho.left - cop.left - co.left, 
                    width: w, 
                    height: h
                });
            }

        }
    });


    $(function(){

            $( "#resizable1").staticblock({});
            $( "#resizable2").staticblock({});
            $( "#resizable3").staticblock({});
            $( "#resizable4").staticblock({});

    });
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent { width:600px; height: 600px; background: blue;}    

#resizable1 { width: 130px; height: 131px; padding: 0em; background: yellow; }
#resizable1 h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }

#resizable2 { width: 85px; height: 50px; padding: 0em; background: yellow; }
#resizable2 h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }

#resizable3 { width: 41px; height: 70px; padding: 0em; background: yellow; }
#resizable3 h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }

#resizable4 { width: 11px; height: 99px; padding: 0em; background: yellow; }
#resizable4 h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="resizable1" class="ui-widget-content">
       test
    </div>
    <div id="resizable2" class="ui-widget-content">
       test
    </div>
    <div id="resizable3" class="ui-widget-content">
       test
    </div>
    <div id="resizable4" class="ui-widget-content">
       test
    </div>
</div>
```